# Retrieve the autocomplete list from another site (NCBI)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, blast

As you can see in the [blast's](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastx&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) page when you try to write something in the organism textbox e.g 'Zea' a drop down list with many suggestions, appears.

As i can understand this info is stored somewhere in the server of NCBI, like in a json file.
So i would like to know if its possible with a technique to retrieve those data and use it in another textbox (with the same idea - drop down list) for a web program im working on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a autocomplete service on this page. You can call it with the following URl.
http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/portal/utils/autocomp.fcgi?dict=taxids_sg&q=zea

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me and some hint on how to use these data ? Can i retrieve them somehow with jQuery ?